# Joining two queries with different where clauses into 1 table

Tags: sql

This is probably a pretty simple question, but I have two separate queries that I would like to join into one table. One of the queries shows sign ups to my website by month and the other query shows sign ups that have made a purchase. I would like to combine the two queries into one table so I have the following table:

```
Month      Sign-ups  Sign-ups with Purchase
Jan 2019   250       40
Feb 2019   500       120
```

How can I do that? Here's my two queries:

Sign ups:

```
select
  count(u.id) as Sign_Ups
  , month(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) as Month
from
   prodjoinreel.users u
where
  year(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) = 2019
group by
  2
order by
  2 asc
```

Sign ups with purchase:

```
select
  count(distinct g.owner) as Sign_Ups_with_Reel
  , month(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) as Month
from
  prodjoinreel.goals g
  right join prodjoinreel.users u on
    g.owner = u.id
where
  year(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) = 2019
group by
  2
order by
  2 asc
```

thank you!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Skip the deprecated ordinal numbers in GROUP BY and ORDER BY, specify the column names (or aliases) instead. Thar would make the query portable and forward compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can just add a `count(distinct u.id)` to the second query:

```
select
  month(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) as Month,
  count(distinct u.id) as Sign_Ups,
  count(distinct g.owner) as Sign_Ups_with_Reel
from
  prodjoinreel.users u
  left join prodjoinreel.goals g on g.owner = u.id
where year(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) = 2019
group by 1
order by 1
```

Note: I changed your `right join` to a `left join`; most people tend to consider that `right join`s are rather counter-intuitive, and favor `left join`s instead.

Comment: You'd want to `group by 1`

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to add another column with a specific where clause that is not applied to the Sign_Ups and Sign_Ups_with_Reel columns?